# Ignoring none applicable data when combining two DataFrames

Tags: python, pandas

so I would like to combine my two dataframes so that the columns from placeholder is added to the matching row from df1. Here are the two dataframes individually.

placeholder looks like:

```
   symbol open     high  ...        previous close     change     change percent
0   MDCO  31.7900  32.7000  ...            31.8600     0.5800            1.8205%
```

df1 looks like:

```
   symbol  ...                  phase
0    MDCO  ...                Phase 2
1    FTSV  ...              Phase 1/2
2    FTSV  ...                Phase 1
3    FTSV  ...                Phase 1
4     NVO  ...                Phase 2
5     PFE  ...  PDUFA priority review
```

This is everything I am doing to my two databases. In case that influences the result in any way.

```
 placeholder = pd.DataFrame(List_Filled)_With_Dictionaries)
placeholder.rename(columns={"01. symbol": "symbol"},inplace=True)


placeholder['symbol'] = placeholder['symbol'].astype(str)
print(placeholder)

Result = pd.concat([Df1,placeholder],axis=1)
Result.set_index('symbol',inplace=True)
```

Here is the result of my current code:

```
              Unnamed: 0  ... 10. change percent
symbol                    ...                   
(MDCO, MDCO)           0  ...            1.8205%
(FTSV, nan)            1  ...                NaN
(FTSV, nan)            2  ...                NaN
(FTSV, nan)            3  ...                NaN
(NVO, nan)             4  ...                NaN
```

I would like it to look like this

```
     symbol  ...              phase    ...     Change Percent
0    MDCO  ...                Phase 2  ...     5%
1    FTSV  ...                Phase 1/2...     2% 
2    FTSV  ...                Phase 1  ...     1%
3    FTSV  ...                Phase 1  ...     4%
4     NVO  ...                Phase 2  ...     2%
5     PFE  ...  PDUFA priority review  ...     1%
```

I was told that what I'm describing doesn't make sense. So if you have any questions please ask as I don't know how else to make this any clearer. I would like the several  `(nan)` to not be there as I will need to run this code multiple times as well as the `unnamed` column.

Edit: Problem solved. Here's how the final solution looked

```
                                                     drug  ... 10. change percent
symbol                                                     ...                   
MDCO                                 Inclisiran - ORION 3  ...            1.8205%
FTSV                                      5F9 + rituximab  ...                NaN
FTSV                                    5F9 + Azacitidine  ...                NaN
FTSV                                                  5F9  ...                NaN
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming *matching row* means *the row having same symbol value*, what you want is not `concat` but `merge` or `join`. Here this should work:

```
Result = Df1.merge(placeholder, on='symbol', out='left')
```

Comment: The problem with that is it gets rid of the other rows from `Df1`  edit: the result is 1 row x 14 columns  vs the 75 rows in Df1

Comment: Figured it out. `Result = Df1.merge(placeholder, on='symbol', how='left')`  worked.      It kept all the data from the `Df1` dataframe and added the columns from the `placeholder` dataframe.

Comment: @backtoback4444: You are right. I have edited my post for future readers